# Klocwork - how to scan cross-platform projects?

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, static-analysis, klocwork

We have a project with a single code base which we build both on Windows and Linux. And we want to run Klocwork code analysis on both Windows and Linux. Currently our approach is:

- We have set up one KW project in the web UI
- Inject and build on Linux, push the results to the server, save the report
- Inject and build on Windows, push the results to the server, save the report

It somehow works, but the problem is that latter scan effectively overwrites results of the first one. If we save report directly after push, then we can still have a saved copy, but if developers want to triage/analyze the hit which is present only in the first build (i.e. some Linux-specific code), then it's almost impossible because KW has already marked this hit as "obsolete" (because it was not present in Windows scan)

Having two projects is not really an option, because 90% of the code is shared and it will cause huge overhead of developers to triage the same hits twice.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to achieve your goal.

**Option 1**: There is a tab under projects called Builds. That can give you the build chain report. here you can see the reports of previous builds.

**Option 2**: Are you using Klocwork desktop tools (Plugins/kwcheck)? If yes, developer will be notified automatically about the new defects/issues that he has produced at his machine. So there may be no question of reviewing Klocwork portal by a developer just to see what are all the issues he has created.

**Option 3**: I see you have mentioned 90% of the code has been shared. Is that meant, your project needs windows dlls and Linux libraries together to build your project?.

If the Answer is YES, please do let me know. i will think about some possible workarounds.

If the Answer is NO, then creating kwtables is one time job and from second time onwards Klocwork can perform incremental analysis (`kwbuildproject ....... --incremental`)

**Option 4**: Creating multiple project is not a bad option. Existing project settings can be replicated and the issue status can be sync. When you push the results to Klocwork server, the results will be pushed from Build Machine to Klocwork web/database server and it creates `/projects_root/My_Project/builds/My_Build_Name/` directory. So, maintaining two Klocwork projects wont make much of a difference.

**Option 5**: Schedule a call with Klocwork support team. They will be happy to assist you with the best possible way.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway. However, none of the options seem solving the issue. Option 1 doesn't work as is, as I said, hits from the first scan are being marked as "obsolete" automatically by KW if they're not present in the second scan. 2 - no. 3 - we build two times on two different build servers, I don't see how incremental scan is related to the question. 4 - as mentioned, with big codebase it will lead to huge overhead to devs because same hits will basically appear twice. 5 - as from my experience, this bloody enterprise tools support is a bit less helpful than no support at all.

Comment: I got that. Thanks for the response. Klocwork do have technical partners all over the world to support their customers. you may try to get in touch with direct Klocwork or a technical partner. If you are from India, you can get connected with https://www.meteonic.com/ though support@meteonic.com